Does this sequence involving multiplication and primorials ever return to $1$?
For clarification: as used throughout this question, the $n$th primorial is "the product of the first $n$ primes" (counting $2$ as the first prime, not the zeroth, such that the primorial of $0$ is $1$.).
Define this integer sequence as follows: begin with the number $1$ as $a_0$. Multiply by $1$, then divide by the largest primorial dividing the result. This gives you $1$ again; therefore, $a_1 = 1$. Now repeat, but multiply by $2$ instead of $1$. Since you get $2$, which can be divided by $2$ (since $2$ is a primorial), we find again $a_2 = 1$. The sequence gets more interesting as you keep going; for example, $a_3 = 3, a_4 = 2, a_5 = 5, $ and $a_6 = 1$. After $a_6$, I have found no more $1$'s. The first few terms of the sequence are
$$1,1,1,3,2,5,1,7,28,42,2,11,22,143,1001,15015, 8, 68, 204, 646, 6460, 646...$$
The sequence is characterized by stretches of subfactorial growth separated by large falls. For example, $a_{50} = 14347428260398132900$, but $a_{51} = 1190$, since $a_{50} \cdot 51$ is divisible by $$614889782588491410 = 2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot11\cdot13\cdot17\cdot19\cdot23\cdot29\cdot31\cdot37\cdot41\cdot43\cdot47.$$
We can also make a sequence documenting the ordinal of the primorial that we divide by for each $a_n$; the following sequence is defined as $b_n = $ the number of prime factors of $\dfrac{a_{n-1} \cdot n}{a_n}$:
$$0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 0, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 6...$$
It becomes immediately apparent that $b_n = 0$ if and only if $n = 2^{k} - 1$. Besides that, it's hard to identify other patterns in this sequence.
My primary question is:

Is there some $n > 6$ such that $a_n = 1$?

Other ramblings: the only numbers besides $1$ that I've seen repeated have been $a_{19} = a_{21} = 646$ and $a_{29} = a_{30} = 29$. Are there any other numbers that repeat?
Also, I cannot ascertain whether there is some $f(n)$ such that $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}f(n) = \infty$ and $f(n) < a_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, that is, whether there is some function that approaches infinity that is a lower bound for the $a_n$ sequence. Obviously, if there were, it would prove that the set of all $n$'s for which $a_n = 1$ is finite, if not limited to the aforementioned examples.
Can someone help me answer my question? Any help predicting the behavior of the sequence would be appreciated. Sorry if my explanation was confusing... I couldn't figure out how to write it out in mathematical notation.
Thanks for your help!
EDIT: With the use of a computer program, I've identified that there are no $1$'s up to $300,000$. Since the numbers grow so quickly I can't calculate actual values, but I know they've gone past a googol for sure. Still, this doesn't answer the question of repeated values, or prove the $1$ question...

If $a_n=1$ then we need that the binary representation of $n$ contains precisely 0 or 1 zeros. This is due to the fact that $a_n$ is even otherwise.

@jorisperrenet Hmm... I wonder if could we use that approach with other prime bases (for example, if $a_n \equiv 1 ,(\text{mod} , 3)$ then the ternary representation of $n$ has to have $k$ zeroes). Clearly for $n | 9$ we must have $a_n \equiv 0 , (\text{mod} ,3)$ but could we extend that further? What about for other primes? I will investigate further.

According to my brute force calculations, there are no 1's up to 300 million. Interestingly, $a_{2^{28}-1}$ has 25296069 prime factors.

I would like to verify that the sequence of the primorials used to generate $a_n$ starts as $$1,1,2,1,1,2,2,30, ...$$ right? Also, I remember that $ k # \geq 3^k$, so perhaps you could use this fact, bound the value of $a_{n+1}$ by another sequence which replaces the $ k# $ with $3^k$, and from there see if you can solve for all possible $n$ such that $a_n = 1$? I am working on a proof using this, but I don't think I will be able to complete it before the bounty ends

@Kraken Your sequence doesn't look quite right, since the only values of $1$ in that sequence are for $n = 2^k -1$; according to my records that sequence begins $$1, 1, 2, 1, 6, 2, 30, 1, 2, 6, 210...$$ although something may be wrong with my counting. That seems like a very strong idea though, if you complete a proof that'd be really cool!

How did you get 6 in the sequence of the primorials? From what I know we never divide by 6 in any of the first few $a_n$..

When you go from $a_3$ to $a_4$: we have $a_3 = 3$, so multiply by $4$ to get $12$, and then the largest primorial you can divide by is $6$ to get a value of $a_4 = 2$.

Oh okay, got it

So this is like a comparison of factorials to primorials.  I don't think it will ever go back to $1$.
